Как получить больше 100 записей в Django 5.0/sqlite?
Я пытаюсь получить записи командой:
resumes = Resume.objects.filter(for_vacancy__icontains=f'"{vacancy_name}"')

В базе 245 подходящих объектов, но resumes.count() выдает только 100. С другими запросами такая же ситуация, не более 100 записей. Как это исправить?
UPD: модель Resume имеет вид:
class Resume(models.Model):
    for_vacancy = models.TextField(max_length=2000)

    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateField()
    updated_at = models.DateField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    salary = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
    total_experience = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    owner_id = models.IntegerField()
    resume_id = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    skills = models.TextField(blank=True)

    contact = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
    education = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
    employments = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
    experience = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
    language = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
    schedules = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

UPD2: Прямой запрос к БД тоже выдает ровно 100 записей
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM vacancy_resume WHERE for_vacancy LIKE %s", [f'%{vacancy_name}%'])
    rows = cursor.fetchall()


Спасибо за быстрый ответ! Resume - модель. Имеет вид
class Resume(models.Model):
for_vacancy = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
created_at = models.DateField()
Когда я пытаюсь получить QuerySet командой Resume.objects.filter(for_vacancy__icontains=f'"{vacancy_name}"'), то получаю 100 записей вместо 245, имеющихся в базе. Я полагаю, что есть какое-то ограничение в базе или в самом Django

По умолчанию никаких ограничений нет, их могли добавить только вы сами (возможно неосознанно)
